# Intro to Android SQLite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I need to learn how to use databases for my application, so I have decided to go with [vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) as most of his other tutorials are very helpful. I just have a few questions to make sure my application will be compatible across devices.

He mentions that his tutorial will use the Async loader class

> This tutorial describes how to use the SQLite database in Android
>   applications. It also     demonstrates how to use existing
>   ContentProvider and how to define new ones. It also     demonstrates
>   the usage of the Loader framework which allows to load data
>   asynchronously.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html shows that the minimum API level is 11?

How should I go about learning SQLite in Android? Should I use this tutorial? I want to make sure I'm using the best standards, yet getting compatibility as far back as possible (At least API level 7)

Answer (score 2):

It's generally best practice to make SQLite calls asynchronously. You could use the Android support library which has `AsyncTaskLoader`, but I usually just extend [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which was introduced in API level 3.

Comment: Would you follow the tutorial listed above? Or would you follow something else?

Comment: @EGHDK yes, good & up-to-date tutorial without flaws. Certainly (one of) the best out there.

Comment: It looks very comprehensive, and like zapl said, up-to-date. If you're looking for a simple introduction to SQLite on Android, it might be more than you need, but it covers good practices. It would be worth going through eventually.

Comment: I guess I'll go through it now, and learn the "hard way". I just want to make sure I'm using the best practices available. Also, @TylerTreat why do you use AsyncTask instead if it's "recommended" to use Async Task Loader?

Comment: Well, there is a little more to it than what I said. `AsyncTask` is very quick and easy to implement, but it can potentially cause memory-leak issues if you have changing screen orientations mid-execution. `AsyncTaskLoader` is better to use if this is a concern for your application, but `Loader` is a newer API so again, you either need to use the support jar or simply use a higher API level. Using `CursorLoader` is probably the most "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The AsyncTaskLoader is supported using the Android support library

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

back to V4.  CursorLoader (subclass of AsyncTaskLoader) is the preferred way for handling SQLite transactions while maintaining smooth UI flow on Android.  Note that CursorLoader does require the use of a ContentProvider, so it's worth looking at ContentProviders as well.